# Swift compiler works until I add another .map(ping) clause

Tags: swift, split

I'm working with some old text files and parsing them with `map` and `reduce`. Here's one working example:

```
onecpart.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
    .reduce("", combine: { $0 + ($1.containsString(":") ? "\n" : " ") + $1 })
    .componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
    .filter({ $0 != "" })
    .map({ $0.componentsSeparatedByString(":") })
    .forEach({ info[$0.first!] = $0.last })
```

Now I'm trying to do something very similar, the main difference being that I have to have two delimiters. So I did this:

```
let parts = original!.characters.split{ $0 == " " || $0 == "," }
    .map{ String($0).trim() }
    .reduce("", combine: { $0 + ($1.containsString("=") ? "\n" : " ") + $1 })
    .componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
```

This code correctly parses the line and returns an array of strings with = in them, but also some empty strings. So to get rid of the empty strings I just want to do:

```
let parts = original!.characters.split{ $0 == " " || $0 == "," }
    .map{ String($0).trim() }
    .reduce("", combine: { $0 + ($1.containsString("=") ? "\n" : " ") + $1 })
    .componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
    .filter({ $0 != "" })
```

Now when I compile, it sticks at the Analyzing stage for a long time, and then fails saying:

`Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions`

I seem to recall this has something to do with the type inference, and I suspect that's because of the use of `characters.split`? Is there a way around this without introducing too much complexity?

Comment: Have you tried adding an intermediate variable, e.g. after the `reduce` step?

Comment: I'm trying variations, and it appears the actual problem is in the very first step. It seems that `componentsSeparatedByString` returns `[String]`, but `characters.split` does not, and that confuses the rest of it.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz I've run into this before. You just need to break up your statement into two separate statements.

Comment: Ok guys, thanks. I had to use three parts in the end. It's definitely that first statement, I think the compiler can't figure out what the return type is supposed to be when they're all strung together, but if you break them up then it can.

Comment: BTW I was sent another example file that used tabs instead of spaces (wow) and had to change one line: `let halves: [String] = original!.characters.split{ $0 == "#" || $0 == "'" || $0 == "\t" }.map{ String($0).trim() }` Adding that `|| $0 == "\t"` made it fail with the same error, while the same line worked fine without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably right about the .characters confusing the compiler.
Here's an alternative way to do it (couldn't find trim() so I replaced it with what I believe would be equivalent).

```
let parts = original!
           .componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: " ,"))     
           .map ({ $0.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString:" ")) })
           .reduce("", combine: { $0 + ($1.containsString("=") ? "\n" : " ") + $1 })
           .componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
           .filter({ $0 != "" })
```

Comment: Oh most excellent Alain! I'm very new to all this map/reduce/filter stuff, but every time I see a solution like this I wonder how I ever lived without it.

Answer (score 0):

Riffing off of Alain's excellent answer, others might find this useful:

```
extension String {
    func componentsSeparatedByStrings(delimiters: [String]) -> [String] {
        guard self.length > 0 else { return [] }
        guard delimiters.count > 0 else { return [] }
        let delims = delimiters.joinWithSeparator("")
        return componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: delims))
    }
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
let parts = mystring.componentsSearatedByStrings([" ",",","\t"])
```

You can use that inline in the examples above and you won't get the compiler errors. *phew*